arquivo gen xlsx e download no react native
I wanted to know if with react-native, I can get values ​​from an asyncstorage and generate an .xlsx file, and download this file, when clicking on a button
it is a json, and has this structure:
const onSubmitDownalodFile = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();

    const obj = AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
    .then((json) => {
        return json
    });

    // is possible create xlsx and download de file her?

    return obj
}

